# Exception raised on attempt to serialize PropertyInfo

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

Is serializing PropertyInfo supposed to be supported? If not, what is the best workaround? I know it is possible to serialize the type (which is supported) and then lookup the property by its attributes - imagine the lookup maybe expensive.

p.s. PropertyInfo is used in implementing functionality similar to DataLoadOptions.LoadWith http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548760.aspx.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using ProtoBuf;

[ProtoContract]
public class A
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public PropertyInfo Property { get; set; }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var value = new A { Property = typeof(string).GetProperty("Length") };
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Raises InvalidOperationException
            // "No serializer defined for type: System.Reflection.PropertyInfo"
            Serializer.Serialize(stream, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Call stack when the `InvalidOperationException` is raised:

```
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.ValueMember.BuildSerializer() Line 316   C#
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.ValueMember.Serializer.get() Line 188 + 0x24 bytes   C#
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.BuildSerializer() Line 421 + 0x1f bytes C#
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.Serializer.get() Line 344 + 0xe bytes   C#
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(int key, object value, ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter dest) Line 592 + 0x44 bytes   C#
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.SerializeCore(ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter writer, object value) Line 178 + 0x14 bytes C#
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Serialize(System.IO.Stream dest, object value, ProtoBuf.SerializationContext context) Line 209 + 0xe bytes C#
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Serialize(System.IO.Stream dest, object value) Line 193 + 0x10 bytes   C#
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize<TestProtoBufNet.A>(System.IO.Stream destination, TestProtoBufNet.A instance) Line 88 + 0x18 bytes    C#
TestProtoBufNet.dll!TestProtoBufNet.UnitTest.TestMethod1() Line 24 + 0x10 bytes C#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add t what @ikh has already said, no that is not a supported type. When I refer to standard BCL types, I'm talking about *common data* types, not reflection types. The entire point of protobuf and protobuf-net is to be data-centric, but `PropertyInfo` etc is implementation, not data. Indeed, WinRT has a very different idea about how much information a `PropertyInfo` should have.

However! If you are determined to serialize it, then note that `Type` *is* supported IIRC. So you could probably do this (completely untested, I'm on an iPad here!) via a surrogate:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class PropertyInfoSurrogate {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static operator implicit PropertyInfoSurrogate(PropertyInfo value) {
        if(value == null) return null;
        return new PropertyInfoSurrogate {
             Type = value.DeclaringType, Name = value.Name
        };
    }
    public static operator implicit PropertyInfo(PropertyInfoSurrogate value) {
        if(value == null) return null;
        return value.Type.GetProperty(value.Name);
    }
}
```

Then, to your model:

```
model.Add(typeof(PropertyInfo), false)
    .SetSurrogate(typeof(PropertyInfoSurrogate));
```

Emphasis: completely untested, but something *like* that should work. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: With just a minor syntax tweak and some logic to handle ambiguous cases with GetProperty, this worked like a charm. Thanks Marc.

Comment: @user1546077 no problem; "a little syntax tweak" - did i get the `operator` syntax reversed? I always do, unfortunately. And when I remember and think "oh, I always get that wrong - reverse them", it turns out I was right *before* I reversed them. Sigh.

Comment: Exactly on the operator syntax. I edited your original response so as soon as the mods approve, your original will look perfect.

Comment: @user1546077 hmmmm... That's odd; I would have expected to be able to see that (since I'm a SE dev, I can see pretty much everything). I wonder if it was rejected. That would be vexing; I'm sure your edit was fine,

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it looks like `PropertyInfo` is not serializable by protobuf-net.  To serialize the data in it, you'd probably have to create a separate `ProtoContract` class that would store the relevant bits of `PropertyInfo`, and use that.

Specifically, reading through the source code for how protobuf-net finds a serializer for a complex type ([here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/protobuf-net/Meta/RuntimeTypeModel.cs) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/protobuf-net/Meta/MetaType.cs#738)), it looks like protobuf can only work with classes that have `[DataContract]`-like attributes, specifically any of the following:

- `[ProtoContract]`,
- [`[DataContract]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx),
- [`[XmlType]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute.aspx).

and will not work with others.

A simple experiment confirms this.  The following code will run without exceptions, but if the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` are commented out, then I get the same exception as you:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;

using ProtoBuf;

namespace ProtobufNetTest2 {
    [DataContract(Name = "Pet", Namespace = "http://www.example.com")]
    public class Pet  {
        [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class DogMessage {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public Pet Dog { get; set; }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var dog = new Pet() {
                Name = "The Dog",
            };

            var dogMessage = new DogMessage() {
                Dog = dog,
            };

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
                Serializer.Serialize(stream, dogMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The author states "support for all standard BCL types" here http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Capabilities. Maybe PropertyInfo isn't a standard BCL type?

Comment: I expect it would be a standard BCL type... but I don't see any code in protobuf-net that would handle that.  `PropertyInfo` is has a `[SerializableAttribute]` attribute, but I don't see any handling of those in protobuf-net either.  Might be better to wait for Marc Gravell to show up to clarify that (he will probably do that soon).

Comment: For the record, protobuf-net supports multiple ways of supporting types without attributes; models can be specified at runtime, certain models can automatically be inferred, and there are surrogates for yet more scenarios. It is quite subtle in the options available.